# Ajax Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) in localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple ajax request like that:

```
<input id="question_i" name="question" type="text">
<button id="btn_AddQuestion" class="form-control">Ajouter</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#btn_AddQuestion" ).click(function() {
    var frm = $('#question_i').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'fonction/AddQuestion.php',
        data: {
            frm: frm
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response)
        }
    })
});
<script>
```

In my AddQuestion.php, I have only an *echo*

And if I look in console log I get :

> Failed to load https://www.domain.fr/fonction/AddQuestion.php:
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I really don't get it why I'm getting this error because I'm working on localhost.

Comment: `I'm working on localhost` The request is being made to an external domain, hence it counts as a cross-domain request and is subject to the Same Origin Policy. As the response does not contains CORS headers you are seeing this error. I'd suggest explicitly calling your local domain (which admittedly your example code is doing, so I assume this is not the actual code that's being executed). If the final production version will actually be making a cross-domain request then you will need to add CORS headers to the response from `seedbox.fr`

Comment: How can I force to use the localhost file ?

Comment: Use a relative path - which the code in your question already appears to be doing, but that cannot be the code that's actually executed, otherwise you would not see this problem

Comment: Working great ! It's fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve

> Failed to load https://www.domain.fr/fonction/AddQuestion.php:
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I force the url in the ajax parameter like :

```
url: 'http://localhost/fonction/AddQuestion.php',
```